# symfony6 - No log in prod env

Tags: symfony, production-environment, symfony6

I have error 500 in prod env and no log are generated.

`/var/www/myapp/var/log` and `/var/log/apache2/myapp_error.log` are both empty.

I [set up permissions as in documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html) but nothing change.

Comment: Check your server logs instead, that might point you in the right direction.

Comment: As i said, there is nothing in my server log.
`/var/log/apache2/error.log` is as empty as `/var/log/apache2/myapp_error.log`

Comment: Check your php.ini and see if `error_log` is enabled and set.

Comment: @Bossman : here is my error config in my used php.ini, i let all by default :  `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`, `display_errors = Off`, `display_startup_errors = Off`, `log_errors = On`. error_log is not set : `;error_log = php_errors.log`. Here is my apache2.conf : `ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite_error.log`. `mysite_error.log` is empty.

Comment: Do you use php-fpm or the apache2 module? If php-fpm, I can maybe help

Comment: make sure you  have no mispritns in `APP_ENV=prod`, and you can try to see if you will get any errors at all by settings `APP_DEBUG=true`. You can try to clean cache in prod like `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`. check permissions, and restart server.

Answer (score 0):

Default in the prod environment, logs are written to STDERR PHP stream
https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html#monolog

You have to configure path in monolog.yaml
nested:
type: stream
path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"